# Android layout could not be loaded in Xamarin

Tags: android, layout, xamarin, cross-platform

I created Xamarin project and when i added android layout, it failed to give me layout in the design view. I have updated my android sdk to 24.3.3 which is the latest one. Below is the image of error i am receiving.

[image: Android Layout could not be loaded]

Please help me. Anyone?

Comment: Please post your axml, if it not too long.

Comment: That layout contains invalid xml... The designer does handle basic syntax errors, but if it can not get at least the first node of the xml tree, it will fail

Comment: Click on the source tab and post your axml code

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the XML to see if it is valid? I would open it in a text editor and check.

Also the names of your layout elements.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the top of your .axml file and/or

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

in the first element